# Участники с репутацией < 2k в списке проверок предлагаемых правок

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок, предлагаемые-правки

Почему люди, у которых намного меньше 2 тысяч баллов репутации отображаются в списке тех, кто проверяет предлагаемые правки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратил на это внимание после того, как внес правку в вопрос участника Kobets Matviy, но до того, как она была принята.

Логично было бы предположить, что сюда попадают даже те, кто принял правку предложенную на свой вопрос/ответ, но, насколько я помню, новички не имеют привилегий одобрять или отклонять предложенные правки.

Comment: На собственный вопрос и ответ -- имеют возможность принять/отклонить правку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше предположение верно. Эти участники, показанные на ваших снимках экрана, приняли или отклонили правки для своих собственных сообщений. Для этого действия нет необходимости обладать привелегией "[Правка вопросов и ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)".

Comment: Насколько мне помнится, когда кто-то правит мои *вопросы*, я никогда не получаю уведомления об этом. Одобрять или отклонять правку собственного вопроса, я, кажется, никогда не решал. Может их просто никогда не правили...

Comment: И еще. Предлагаемые правки утверждаются **только** авторами вопросов/ответов, или и сообществом тоже?

Comment: По идее уведомления должны быть. Если правка была от 2к+ участника, вы получите уведомление пост-фактум, если правка от должна пройти одобрение, вы получите уведомление об ожидающей правки и сможете перейти в очередь предлагаемых правок, чтобы принять или отклонить её.

Comment: То есть если я (~1500) предлагаю правку вопроса другого участника (~10), то я полагаюсь только на его адекватность? И при этом, если от отклоняет *мою* правку, то точно такую же правку может внести любой участник (2к+)?

Comment: Все правки от участников с низкой репутацией попадают в очередь предлагаемых правок, где более опытные товарищи или сам автор сообщения могут принять или отклонить их. Даже если два обычных участника обработают правку, автор сообщения или модератор могут изменить это решение.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо, вроде бы понятно.