# Правки, знак "Смотритель" и уровень репутации ниже 2k

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок, знаки, предлагаемые-правки

Периодически замечаю у пользователей с небольшими уровнями репутации (иногда - меньше сотни) наличие знака ["Смотритель"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/82/custodian). На странице, описывающей подробности получения этого знака, обычно пишется, что получен он **"за проверку [Предлагаемые правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history)"**.
Но когда я захожу по ссылке в очередь предлагаемых правок, я получаю сообщение: **"Для проверки предложенных правок требуется минимум 2k баллов репутации"**.
Очень хочется понять, как можно, имея минимальную репутацию, получить знак "Смотритель"?

Update: Как выяснилось, по сути эта же тема обсуждалось [с точки зрения пользователя с высоким рейтингом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6131/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-2k-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA), имеющего доступ к перечню предлагаемых правок, который обнаружил в списке проверяющих тех пользователей, о которых задал свой вопрос я. Предлагаю оставить оба вопроса, т.к. несмотря на то, что в них обсуждается одна и та же тема, проблема выглядят несколько иначе в зависимости от того, с какой стороны на нее смотреть.

Comment: Ограничение 2К не распостраняется на ваши собственные вопросы/ответы. Вы принимаете/отклоняете предложенные правки и получаете знаки.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6131/178988

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваши комментарии! Правильно ли я понимаю, что этот знак может быть получен участником с низким рейтингом (<2k) дважды: один раз за одобрение этим участником правки своего сообщения другим участником с низким рейтингом и один раз за одобренную кем-то предложенную этим участником правку сообщения другого участника? Или это считается одним и тем же типом проверки?

Comment: @IvanOlshansky, вряд ли.

Comment: Предлагаю оставить обе темы. Мотивацию я изложил в виде апдейта к вопросу.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky, на самом деле вопросы-дубликаты сохраняются на сайте, и не удаляются. Просто ссылка на дубликат явно указывает, где искать ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @mymedia, понятно. Спасибо за разъяснение!